# MPI_scatterv return MPI_ERROR_TRUNCATE in fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran

What s wrong with the following code? It works fine when I run it with 1,2 and 5 cpus,
while with 3 cpus, it breaks at (1), and with 4 cpus, it breaks at (2). In both the cases the error reads:

An error occurred in MPI_Scatterv
reported by process [3248685057,3]
on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated.

Probably the problem is correlated with memory allocation, but I cannot understand it deeply...(I am not totally confident about how I allocated the distributed variables (3)) Some suggestion is warmly accepted

```
program import_and_divide
implicit none
      include 'mpif.h'

      integer                            :: i, k, io, n ,nnz
      integer,allocatable, dimension(:)  :: Ai, Aj
      real*8, allocatable, dimension(:)  :: Aa, Ab, x
      integer*4                          :: rank, mpi_stat, size
      integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: sendcounts, displ, sendcounts1, displ1
      integer                            :: n_distro
      integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: ia, ja
      real*8, allocatable, dimension(:)  :: a, b

        n = 5
        nnz = 13
!.. Initialize MPI.
      call MPI_INIT(mpi_stat)
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, mpi_stat)
      call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, mpi_stat)

      if (rank.eq.0) then
              allocate(Ai(n+1), Aj(nnz), Aa(nnz), Ab(n), x(n))

      Ai = (/0, 3, 5, 8, 11, 13/)
      Aj = (/0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 1, 4/)
      Aa = (/1, -1, -3, -2 , 5, 4, 6, 4, -4, 2, 7, 8, -5/)
        Ab(:) = ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
         x(:) = 0.d0
        print*, 'Number of cpus: ', size
        print*, 'n, nnz: ', n, nnz
      endif

      call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_stat)

      allocate(sendcounts(size), displ(size), sendcounts1(size), displ1(size))

      n_distro=(n+1)/size
      k = 0 
      do i=1,size 
       if (i<size) then
               sendcounts(i) = n_distro
       else
               sendcounts(i) = (n+0)-(size-1)*n_distro
       endif

       displ(i) = k
       k = k + sendcounts(i)
      end do

      if (rank.eq.0) then
              displ1 = Ai(displ+1)
                do i=1,size-1
                        sendcounts1(i) = displ1(i+1)-displ1(i) 
                end do
                sendcounts1(size) = nnz-displ1(size)
      endif

      call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat)
      if (rank.eq.0) then
        print*, 'Sendcounts: ', sendcounts
        print*, 'Displ: ', displ
      endif
      
      call MPI_BCAST(displ1,shape(displ1), MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat)
      call MPI_BCAST(sendcounts1, shape(sendcounts1), MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat)

      do i=0,size-1
        if (i.eq.rank) then
                allocate(b(sendcounts(i+1)), ia(sendcounts(i+1)+1) ,&
                         a(sendcounts1(i+1)), ja(sendcounts1(i+1)))  !(3)
                ia(:) = rank
                ja(:) = 0
                b(:)  = 0.d0
                a(:) = 0.d0
        end if
        call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat)     
      end do

      call MPI_scatterv(Ab, sendcounts, displ, MPI_DOUBLE,&
                         b, sendcounts, MPI_DOUBLE,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat) ! (2) breaks here with mpirun -np 4
      call MPI_scatterv(Ai, sendcounts+1, displ, MPI_INT,&
                        ia, sendcounts+1, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat) 
      
     call MPI_scatterv(Aa, sendcounts1, displ1, MPI_DOUBLE,&
                        a, sendcounts1, MPI_DOUBLE,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat)
     call MPI_scatterv(Aj, sendcounts1, displ1, MPI_INT,& 
                       ja, sendcounts1, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpi_stat)     ! (1) breaks here with mpirun -np 3
     
     call MPI_FINALIZE(mpi_stat)
end
```

When I replace `include "mpif.h"` with `use mpi` and I got the following errors:

```
There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_bcast’
There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatterv’.
```

I also add `-fcheck=all` and this option provides this additional info (when compiled with mpif.h):

`Allocatable actual argument 'ab' is not allocated`

but this do not clarify my idea.

If the arrays `Ai, Aj, Ab, Aa` are allocated on all the processors, I got the same behaviour (works with 1,2 and 5 cpus and breaks with 3 and 4 cpus) and disappear the message `Allocatable actual argument 'ab' is not allocated`

If I replace `sendcounts` and `sendcounts1` in the second half of MPI_scatterv with `sendcounts(rank+1)` and `sendcounts1(rank+1)`, the code seems to work fine only if I remove the compiler flag `-fcheck=all`/`-fsanitize=address`(if the arrays Ai,Aj,Aa,Ab are allocated on all the processes as well as if allocated only on one process (rank=0)). With one of these two options I got the following error:

`==25041==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks`

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. It is really recommended to use `use mpi`  instead of `include "mpif.h". That way the compiler can better check the correctness of your calls. Please try that and also enable all compiler checks in gfortran `gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all`. Alternatively, you can also try `-fsanitize=address`  instead of `-fcheck=all`.

Comment: I replace include"mpif.h" with use mpi and I got the following errors: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_bcast’, There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_scatterv’.  I also add -fcheck=all and this option provides this additional info (when compiled with mpif.h): "Allocatable actual argument 'ab' is not allocated", but this do not clarify my idea

Comment: Do not use comments for important information, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: The option does NOT break the code, it finds your error!!! This is the reason why you should always use these options. You have to allocate your arrays in all processes.

Comment: Instead of `sendcounts` in the second half of arguments to `MPI_Scatterv`, you should pass `sendcounts(rank+1)`. Otherwise, all ranks will try to receive `sendcounts(1)` elements. Same for `sendcounts1`.

Comment: Do not worry about the Memory leaks message, you do not use any pointers. It will always be displayed, unless you deallocate your arrays.

Comment: ok, but as you said before, the option does not break the code, so I do not understand why when I use that option the code breaks while without, it works...Anyway, thank Vladimir F and Hristo Iliev

Comment: The send buffer of `MPI_Scatterv()` is only relevant on the root rank according to the MPI standard, but the compiler is not aware of that and issues a “false positive” when the buffer is not allocated on non root ranks. So always allocate the buffers on all ranks, or do not use that option.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The Fortran standard is very clear that allocatable array *must* be allocated when passing as an argument. using the option or not. Not allocating it makes the program not standard conforming, undefined behaviour, nose demons and so on. What is supoosed to be touched in the subroutine is only secondary.

Comment: @Andrea it does not break the code. It finds an existing issue. Often a code seems to be working even when it contains errors that later cause big problems. If your lesson from this is that you should not use bug checking options, it is very sad and can cause you big problems in future. That is for the "not allocated" message from `-fcheck=all`. Do use it for checking your programs. The sanitize option is not Fortran-specific and therefore the leaks message is a false positive, it will desappear when you deallocate your arrays at the end.

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks for pointing the right thing to do.

Comment: I don't say that I don't want use the option ``-fcheck=all``, but this flag, during the compiling stage, does not provide any warning or error messages